# How to render first slide and render other slides in $timeout?

Tags: ionic-framework

I have some slides, maybe 20 or more than, in ion-slide-box, and each slide has ion-view tag, and some slides has an image, which can zoom. I meet some difficulty that when I click an button to show the ion-slide-box on ion-view, it needs waiting some time. Some I want to render the first slide and render others in $timeout. But I don't know how to do it.
Is there anyone who knows how to achieve it? Thanks a lot.

**SUPPLEMENT:**
[image]
[image]

Comment: You can provide code?

Comment: Hi sioesi, please see the supplement.Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a way to solve the problem. [image]